# Путь с свойству с помощью рефлексии C#

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Есть массив объектов:

```
ist<product_description> product_descriptions = new List<product_description>();
        product_descriptions.Add(new product_description());
        product_descriptions.Add(new product_description());
        product_descriptions.Add(new product_description());
```

И собственно сам объект:

```
public class product_description
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string meta_title { get; set; }
    public string meta_description { get; set; }
}
```

Никак не могу прийти к решению как с помощью рефлексии получить путь к свойствам в таком формате:

```
product_description[0][name]
product_description[0][description]
product_description[0][meta_title]
product_description[0][meta_description]
product_description[1][name]
product_description[1][description]
product_description[1][meta_title]
product_description[1][meta_description]
product_description[2][name]
product_description[2][description]
product_description[2][meta_title]
product_description[2][meta_description]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаем названия свойств, получаем  название типа, выводим на экран

```
List<product_description> product_descriptions = new List<product_description>();
product_descriptions.Add(new product_description());
product_descriptions.Add(new product_description());
product_descriptions.Add(new product_description());

var props = typeof(product_description).GetProperties()
    .Select(x => x.Name)        
    .ToArray();

var typename = nameof(product_description);

for (var i = 0; i < product_descriptions.Count; i++)
    foreach (var p in props)
        Console.WriteLine($"{typename}[{i}][{p}]");
```

Результат

```
product_description[0][name]
product_description[0][description]
product_description[0][meta_title]
product_description[0][meta_description]
product_description[1][name]
product_description[1][description]
product_description[1][meta_title]
product_description[1][meta_description]
product_description[2][name]
product_description[2][description]
product_description[2][meta_title]
product_description[2][meta_description]
```

Comment: Минусаторам было бы здорово пояснить, за что именно минусы

Comment: Не знаю за что минус был. Как по мне - хорошее решение. +1 для справедливости

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц спасибо :)

Comment: Отличное решение, полностью решило мой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class product_description
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string meta_title { get; set; }
    public string meta_description { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<product_description> product_descriptions = new List<product_description>();
        product_descriptions.Add(new product_description(){
            name = "name0",
            description = "description0",
            meta_title = "meta_title0",
            meta_description = "meta_description0"
        });
        product_descriptions.Add(new product_description(){
            name = "name1",
            description = "description1",
            meta_title = "meta_title1",
            meta_description = "meta_description1"
        });
        product_descriptions.Add(new product_description(){
            name = "name2",
            description = "description2",
            meta_title = "meta_title2",
            meta_description = "meta_description2"
        });

        var props = typeof(product_description).GetProperties().ToArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < product_descriptions.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.GetValue(product_descriptions[i]));
            }
        }       
    }
}
```